# my question is about python code i have this codes I wonder why the value is (2)?

Tags: python-2.7

#ReadTemperatureRead Temperature sensor

def ReadTemperature(places):

humidity,temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor,pin)

temperature = round(temperature,places)

return temperature

while True:

#Take Temperature reading via DHT22

temperature_percentage = ReadTemperature(2)

Comment: please use the `code` format for posting code

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/738636/raspberry-pi/micro-controllers/python-codes